# pivot table not showing totals with conditional formatting

Tags: amazon-quicksight

When I apply conditional formatting (gradient background) to a QuickSight pivot table, the Total row does not show any values. If I remove the conditional formatting, the values on the Total row appear. The image shows the same (duplicated) pivot table. The one with conditional formatting shows no Totals. The one without conditional formatting shows Totals.

Anyone else encounter this? I'm stumped... [QuickSight Pivot Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tIe9H.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

To apply conditional formatting to the TOTALS in the QS dashboard, you can follow below approach and this should solve your problem:

1. Click on option at the top right of your pivot visual and click on conditional formatting.
2. On the various conditions you have mentioned, click on the button besides it as shown in the image below.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQRRZ.png)

3. After clicking this there will be three checkboxes values, subtotals and totals. Check the totals box and you are done.

Do let me know if it works.