# pivot table not showing totals with gradient background conditional formatting

Tags: pivot-table, conditional-formatting, amazon-quicksight

I've ran into the same problem as this user: [pivot table not showing totals with conditional formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71961700/pivot-table-not-showing-totals-with-conditional-formatting) where the totals disappear once you apply a conditional formating background to it.

Applying the solid background color to the totals does fix the issue as described in the answer of that ticket, however this option is not available for gradient background colors. Is there any way to fix this or am i missing something?

Thanks in advance